# Primeng Field Reset Form only works for first time

Tags: angular, primeng, angular10

StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-password-demo-tnbf5v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Now I have `p-password` field, and a reset button, I have used this `p-password` field inside a formGroup.

Reset button is for resetting all the fields, but for `p-password` it only works for first time, from second time, it only resets data in model, but in UI the value remains in the input field,
I spent days for solving this issue, but not able to find a proper solution

Any help would be appreciated

html

```
<form [formGroup]="passwordForm">
  <p-password formControlName="old_password" [toggleMask]="true" [feedback]="false"></p-password>

  <button type="button" value="Reset" (click)="resetPasswordForm()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  passwordForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.passwordForm = this.fb.group({
      old_password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  resetPasswordForm() {
    this.passwordForm.reset();
    this.passwordForm.markAsPristine();
    this.passwordForm.markAsUntouched();
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked after I updated the stackblitz to use angular 12.0.3, and primeng 11.4.2. Maybe your library versions are out of alignment.

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks for quick help, but problem is I can't upgrade app :(